# Caterpillar D11 (set 42131). will not calibrate the blade tilt function

Tags: technic, powered-up, control-plus

I finished building my LEGO technic CAT D11 set and I tried using the C+ app but the first try It did nothing so I searched and found I accidentally missed a gear and put it in my extra pieces box so I put it where it went and tried to calibrate again this time it raised the blade but did not tilt it. I did some research and found it might be the shifter so I looked and could not find the problem. when I calibrate it shifts into the first mode but when its done it doesn't shift into second gear. (desperately looking for help) if you can help please respond. thanks. :)